# HTML5 Canvas undo isn't working properly in IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have started creating an Undo script for the canvas element. It is far from complete, but the basics are in place. The code runs well in Chrome, Safari, and Opera yet throws errors in IE and Firefox. The error in Firefox is `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object` and the error on IE is `Invalid calling object`.

Both errors are about the line that is: `var original = context[p];` in the `bind()` function.

**Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/evankennedy/cDdJd/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers don't like it when you try to wrap methods of a native object in your own code.  It's a security "feature".

You would be better off creating an entirely new object class that wraps the context and then proxies its methods (and properties).

This would also avoid the need for your `history.write` state since the `undo` and `redo` methods would still have access to the original methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because your script lacks comments and the question does not explain it in detail it is difficult to figure out what you are doing.

However, if you need to store the state of the `<canvas>` you need copy all of its pixels to a memory buffer. Canvas or context objects cannot be cloned because they are bound to the current UI state.

To access canvas data use getImageData()

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29

And restore it with corresponding put pixels call.

Comment: he's storing a stack of all of the methods called on the canvas, not its pixel state.  "undo" erases the canvas and redraws everything up to the last operation.